# I want to change product name in order details page within the WordPress dashboard WooCommerce

Tags: woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I have a form that contains a dropdown field, and I change the product name according to that dropdown.

I have changed the name in the cart, checkout, and order section detail on the thank you page using these hooks:

add_filter('woocommerce_cart_item_name', 'change_product_name_in_cart', 10, 3);
add_filter('woocommerce_checkout_item_name', 'change_product_name_in_cart', 10, 3);
add_filter('woocommerce_order_item_name', 'change_product_name_in_cart', 10, 3);

However, I am unable to change the product name in the order detail page within the WordPress dashboard.

This screenshot is of the order detail section where the name has been changed
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AWUuS.png)

And this is the screenshot where I am unable to change the product name.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EDYNJ.png)

I try different hook to change product name in order of product page in Woocommerce WordPress dashboard. But I am unable to do so.

Comment: There is no particular hook for that.

Comment: You need to copy order-details template in your theme and change it to your needs.

Comment: I think it would be more convenient to add those drop-down values as order item metadata, that way it would automatically display right below the product name everywhere (thankyou page, e-mails, admin dashboard,...).